# How to call a GUI (Swing) from a Class to the Main Class?

Tags: java, swing

I've seen similar questions answered but could not find an answer to my question. I have a Main Class, which has it's own JFrame. However, I've created a different Class where I've created another JFrame that prompts the user for some data. The Main Class is the main app. The secondary class is supposed to pop up before the main class GUI runs. I've created 2 different packages for each one of the Classes.
So, I'm trying to call an Object of the secondary Class from Main Class but the interface does not appear. I do not get any errors in the code and the App runs as if the Object of secondary Class is not being called at all. I am new to Java and would appreciate some lights on this.

My code is as follows:

**Main Class**

```
public class TempConverter extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TempConverter() {
        initComponents();
    }

// More code

public static void main(String args[]) {

    DemoUserData test = new DemoUserData();

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            test.setVisible(true);
            new TempConverter().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

**Secondary Class**

```
public class DemoUserData extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public DemoUserData() {
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `setVisible` on a `JPanel`, not on its parent `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JFrame is the main window. Before it is shown at the very early start a **splash screen** maybe shown, normally a small rectange with a logo.

It however seems, you want some input dialog, like say a login. That cannot be a JPanel, but must be a top-level window: JFrame or JDialog. Or one of the JOptionPane dialogs (asking string input, or whatevever).

Maybe you should make a JFrame for your current JPanel, run that.

.

```
   DemoUserDataFrame test = new DemoUserDataFrame(this);

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            test.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    public class DemoUserDataFrame extends JFrame {

        //private final JFrame tempConverter;

        public DemoUserDataFrame(final JFrame tempConverter) {
            //this.tempConverter = tempConverter;
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    tempConverter.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
        ...
    }
```

In the above, closing test, will make the main JFrame visible.

In order to have a better overview, have the classes not refer one to another, you might look into the Model-View-Controller concept. Then there is one global "Controller" class as intermediator for all business logic. It holds the data (Model), and so on.

Comment: :-) don't use dot character at the end of the sentence, because breaking the code block

Comment: Yes. I've simply changed it to a JFrame and it worked fine. Thanks for your help.